# N+1 query optimization problem with Django custom user

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-custom-user, django-select-related

I override the Django's built-in user `django.contrib.auth.user` and I created app called `core` for this purpose I override it like this in core/models.py path:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

also I changed the corresponds form and django admin.

by the way I have `store` app which is contain several models, but problem is the every model of my store app need to go and create separately query for each user in database. here is my `customer` and `comment` model:

```py
class Customer(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='customer')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='favourite', blank=True)
```

and my `comments` model is:

```py
class Comment(models.Model)
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        waiting = 'w', 'Waiting'
        approved = 'a', 'Approved'
        not_approved = 'na', 'Not Approved'
    
    author = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    body = models.TextField()
    raiting = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)], blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.waiting)
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I use this query in drf ModelViewSet for catch the comments with it's corresponding author:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
        product_pk = self.kwargs["product_pk"]
        return Comment.objects.select_related('author__user').filter(product_id=product_pk).all()
```

but in debug toolbar still I have multiple similar queries and here there are:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `core_customuser` WHERE `core_customuser`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 21
 7 similar queries.

SELECT ••• FROM `core_customuser` WHERE `core_customuser`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 21
 7 similar queries.

SELECT ••• FROM `core_customuser` WHERE `core_customuser`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 21
 7 similar queries.

SELECT ••• FROM `core_customuser` WHERE `core_customuser`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 21
 7 similar queries.

SELECT ••• FROM `core_customuser` WHERE `core_customuser`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 21
 7 similar queries.

SELECT ••• FROM `core_customuser` WHERE `core_customuser`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 21
 7 similar queries.

SELECT ••• FROM `core_customuser` WHERE `core_customuser`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 21
 7 similar queries.
```

please help!

The N+1 query problem when create custom user in Django

Comment: Can you provide more info? Such as for which method of viewset do you get the result, is it customized? Or mainly how do you further process the results of queryset? Also you refer  to product_id field in your query but i dont see it in the models, I suppose it is a field in the Comment model.

Comment: @pazkou I add almost my full model, and in addition that filter don't related to the question it's just filtering for show comments refer to specific product with specific id.